# How can I add a image to module in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created a simple hello world module can someone please tell me how to add an image below Hello World.

I need to add image to phtml file

> phtml file like below

```
<h2>Hello World></h2>
<img src = "<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/demo.jpg')"
```

> images directory like below

```
app/code/Test/HelloWorld/view/frontend/web/images
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of your code

Comment: I edit that can u give me a solution now sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code,

`<img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Test_HelloWorld::images/demo.jpg'); ?>" />`